# How to change document root of a website and enforce "https" only?

Tags: .htaccess

I am choosing document root via `.htaccess` in a following manner -

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !web/
RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1 [L]
```

How can enforce all requests to `https` too ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on  [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !web/
RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1 [L]
```

**Note** clear browser cache the test

Comment: @Robin see update and clear cache then test , let me know the result